# Running a webapplication in tomcat during tests in Jenkins CI

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins, continuous-integration

I want to do this in a jenkins job:

1. Build a webapp.
2. Start tomcat with previously built webapp.
3. Run jmeter job against started tomcat
4. Verify
5. Stop tomcat

The only parts I'm struggling with is 2 and 5. I've tried running an ant-target that simply runs Bootstrap class with correct catalina.base args etc. Tomcat starts correctly but here is the problem, the start tomcat task is never finished, jenkins just waits until a manually stop the job, so im stuck at bullet 2.

This seems to be a pretty common flow, is there any alternatives for doing this?

/Thanks

Comment: Have you considered running [jetty embedded](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty) instead of tomcat?

Comment: Well, we run tomcat in production and I would rather use the same environment in my tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding **spawn="true"** to my java-task in ant.
The drawback is that I don't see tomcats output in jenkins console, but I can live with that.